# Capturar imagem da webcam e salvar a cada 1 segundo?

Tags: java, imagem, opencv, webcam

Estou fazendo um projeto em que a webcam padrão tira fotos a cada 1 segundo utilizando o opencv.
No meu code, ao clique do botão capturar você seleciona a pasta onde quer e ele captura uma foto. Preciso fazer um loop para que ele capture fotos e salve.

```
public class jfmPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    VideoCaptura webCam;
    ExibeQuadro exibeQuadro;
    Thread executor;
  private DaemonThread myThread = null;
    int count = 0;
    VideoCapture webSource = null;

    Mat frame = new Mat();
    MatOfByte mem = new MatOfByte();


    class DaemonThread implements Runnable
    {
    protected volatile boolean runnable = false;

    @Override
    public  void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            while(runnable)
            {
                if(webSource.grab())
                {
    try
                        {
                            webSource.retrieve(frame);
   Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
   Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));

   BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
   Graphics g=jlbCaptura.getGraphics();

   if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() -150 , 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null))

   if(runnable == false)
                            {
    System.out.println("Going to wait()");
    this.wait();
   }
}
catch(Exception ex)
                         {
   System.out.println("Error");
                         }
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        int returnVal = jFileChooser1.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
        Highgui.imwrite(file.getPath(), frame);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Acesso negado.");
    }
    }
```

Comment: A dúvida é como executar uma thread a cada *x* segundos?

Comment: Isso mesmo, alem de como aplicar a esse código.

Answer (score 1):

Eu implementei uma classe simples chamada `TimedWebcam` utilizando o [webcam-capture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) do sarxos:

**TimedWebcam.java:**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimedWebcam {

    private final Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();

    public TimedWebcam() {
        this.webcam.setViewSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    }

    public void take(int times, int internalInSeconds, String folder) {
        this.webcam.open();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Saving image " + i.toString() + '.');
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(internalInSeconds);
                ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(), "PNG", new File(folder + "\\image" + i.toString() + ".png"));
            } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        this.webcam.close();
    }

}
```

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimedWebcam t = new TimedWebcam();
        t.take(5, 1, "."); // Salva 5 imagens na pasta do projeto a cada 1 segundo.
    }

}
```

Como pode ver, a classe possui um método chamado "take" que pega 3 argumentos: Um para a quantidade de takes, outro para o intervalo em segundos entre cada um, e uma pasta destino onde eles serão salvos em .png. Utilizo a classe [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) para causar o delay. Não tenho experiência com o opencv, mas garanto que o webcam-capture é uma das melhores libs pra trabalhar com a webcam disponíveis para o Java. A lib virá num arquivo de nome "*webcam-capture-0.3.10-dist*" (Por exemplo), e terá de adicionar no build-path do seu projeto o "*webcam-capture-0.3.10.jar*", assim como as libs que ele utiliza: "*bridj-0.6.2.jar*" e "*slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar*".

Não utilizei o Swing / envolvi interface gráfica porque não é necessário para o exemplo, mas é bem simples de fazê-lo verificando os exemplos no github.

Comment: O metodo TimedWebcam na classe main pode ser alocado em um jButton?

Comment: @JonathanGaldino, TimedWebcam não é um método, é uma classe separada em seu próprio arquivo .java* (*Ela possui um método de mesmo nome, o "construtor" da classe, mas não acredito que referia-se ao mesmo). TimedWebcam possui o método "take", como eu expliquei, e esse pode ser facilmente chamado / executado dentro de um ActionListener de um JButton. Resumindo, é muito simples fazer o que você quer (Tirar as fotos ao clicar em um botão).